# DbContext won't accept named connection string for LocalDb

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have app.config like this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=MrBoy;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

In my DbContext class, it works fine if I copy-paste the connection-string e.g.

```
: base("Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=MrBoy;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False")
```

But if I specify

```
:base("name=MyDB")
```

I get an error from my application and from the Package manager console:

> "The connection string 'MyDB' in the application's configuration file
>   does not contain the required providerName attribute."

Why is a valid connection-string not accepted? Is there a workaround other than passing the connection-string manually into my constructor?

Comment: Shouldn't you just pass in `MyDB` and not `name=MyDB`? Perhaps not, but you should have `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` in your connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
         <add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=MrBoy;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Connectionstrings require a provider type.  Setting it as entity context != defining the connection string.  The type is assumed when you are setting context.